# MongoDB Combining Collections - Not Populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Trying to combine a client and an account collection.

When I look use a res.send(client), I only get the account id's. I am not sure how to populate the fields to push account info into clients. I have seen some one to many solutions, but can't figure out this two way thing.

Here's what I get:

```
{"accounts":["5fba8c2f8e5610374463caab","5fba8d49ae11d93c40ce08d9","5fba8dcfb4192a22d469eeef"],"_id":"5fba8bf1407032134c4c22b4","company":"Testing2","contact":"Testing2","phone":5555,"email":"Testing2","city":"Testing2","state":"Testing2","zip":5555555,"__v":3}
```

This is the routing I am using (based on a course that seems to work fine for them(?)):

```
app.post('/clients/:id/accounts', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const client = await Client.findById(id);
    const { name, location, tid } = req.body;
    const account = new Account({ name, location, tid })
    client.accounts.push(account);
    account.client = client;
    await account.save();
    await client.save();
    res.send(client);
    // res.redirect(`/clients/${client._id}`)
    
})
```

Here are the two models I am working with:
Clients:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
   const { Schema } = mongoose;

   const ClientSchema = new Schema({
   company: String,
   contact: String,
   phone: Number,
   email: String,
   city: String,
   state: String,
   zip: Number,
   accounts: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
    },
   ]
   });

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

And the account model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    client: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Client'
    }],
    description: String,
    contact: String,
    tid: String,
    loader: String,
    surcharge: Number,
    payout: Number,
    net: Number,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

SonOfZappa

Answer (score 1):

If you are using moongose, [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I have figured this may be the issue. I have seen populate as a solution, but I am not sure where to implement it. Does it go in the models? Routing? Etc? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I would place `const updatedClient = await Client.findById(id).populate('account');` before `res.send(updatedClient)`, but maybe there is a better way to do it.